# Need to compare times in Perl; how to deal with timezone?

Tags: perl, datetime

I have log files that have timestamps like:

```
Fri Nov 30 10:19:35:152.92 PST 2012
Fri Nov 30 10:19:35:228.8 PST 2012
or even:
Thu Nov 29 14:20:58:3.44 PST 2012
Fri Nov 30 10:27:50:742 PST 2012
```

I am very new to Perl, but it is what everyone here uses, so I'm trying to learn it fast (just started this job).  I need to be able to compare the timestamps (I'm merging logfiles whose times may overlap and need all the timestamps consecutive in the resultant file).
Here is the subroutine where I extract and format the time into a string I can compare:

```
my %months = ( 'Jan'=>1, 'Feb'=>2, 'Mar'=>3, 'Apr'=>4, 'May'=>5, 'Jun'=>6, 'Jul'=>7,
'Aug'=>8, 'Sep'=>9, 'Oct'=>10, 'Nov'=>11, 'Dec'=>12);

sub to_comparable {
    my $date = shift;
    my ($mmm, $d, $H, $M, $S, $mils, $fra, $tz, $Y) = $date =~ 
        m{^<\w{3} (\w{3}) (\d{1,2}) (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,3})[.]{0,1}(\d{0,2}) (\w{3}) (\d{4})>}
            or return undef;
    if ($mils eq "") { $mils = 0; }
    if ($fra eq "") { $fra = 0; }
    my $m = $months{$mmm};
    return sprintf('%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d%03d%02d',$Y,$m,$d,$H,$M,$S,$mils,$fra);
}
```

This works fine as long as the timestamps all come from the same timezone. However, I want to make sure that they work OK for logs that overlap the change from standard time and daylight savings time (or if I get logs from other timezones). I thought perhaps the DateTime package would do the trick, but I'm confused as to how to use the timezone to get comparable times. I can create a date/time object except for what to use for the timezone. 
In my testing, I added the following after mapping the month:

```
    my $ns = sprintf('%03d.%02d',$mils,$fra);
    $ns *= 1000;

    my $dt = DateTime->new(
      year       => $Y,
      month      => $m,
      day        => $d,
      hour       => $H,
      minute     => $M,
      second     => $S,
      nanosecond => $ns,
      time_zone  => "$tz",
  );
```

This results in the error "Invalid offset: PST".
I found the note:"It is strongly recommended that you do not rely on these names for anything other than display. These names are not official, and many of them are simply the invention of the Olson database maintainers. Moreover, these names are not unique. For example, there is an "EST" at both -0500 and +1000/+1100." 
and elsewhere: "The short names for time zones are not unique, and so any attempt to determine the actual time zone from such a name involves guessing. Use the long names instead."

I have no control over the timezone display I am given, so I don't know what to do now. If I use "PST8PDT" or "America/Los_Angeles", how do I indicate whether the given time is standard or daylight savings? And is there a conversion for the timezones in the US to timezones that DateTime will accept? Can someone please help me figure this out? My seemingly trivial project of merging log files is taking forever and my boss thinks I'm an idiot. :-(

Comment: You're not an idiot, you're being careful.  Some people would have ignored this and then someone else would have to find their bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a pity so many log files use such a poor choice of timestamp format. I recommend [RFC 3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) (which is also one of the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats).

Anyway, on to the question.

Create a mapping to translate your source system's identifiers definitions into the standard names or offsets accepted by the `time_zone` argument of the constructor.

```
my %time_zones = (
   EST => '-0500',
   PST => '-0800',
   PDT => '-0700',
   ...
);
```

Then just pass the offset using the `time_zone` argument.

```
$ perl -MDateTime -E'say
   DateTime->new(
      year => 2012, month => 11, day => 4,
      hour => 1, minute => 16, second => 0,
      time_zone => "-0800",
   )->epoch;
'
1352020560

$ perl -MDateTime -E'say
   DateTime->new(
      year => 2012, month => 11, day => 4,
      hour => 1, minute => 16, second => 0,
      time_zone => "-0700",
   )->epoch;
'
1352016960

$ perl -E'say 1352020560 - 1352016960'
3600
```

Comment: It's worse than a pity the times are stupid. :-) If I convert all the times (currently using PST or PDT) to use "America/Los_Angeles", how can it possibly know whether a time is PST or PDT during the repeated hour in the fall? For example, if I create a DateTime object of Nov 4, 2012, 1:15 AM in the "America/Los_Angeles" timezone, how does it know whether the time is standard or daylight savings?

Comment: I might have if I understood what you wrote. :-) Sorry I'm very new to Perl, and I don't get it. In any case I don't want to get the offset from the DateTime object. Creating a DateTime object with DateTime->new does not allow input of the offset, so I still don't see how to put the standard vs daylight savings into the object. So if I have a times of Nov 4, 2012, 1:16 AM PST and Nov 4, 2012, 1:15 AM PDT, how do I get them into a format where it will tell me that the PDT time is after the PST time?

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't make the connection of the hash table before. The clarification really helped. I have implemented it that way (hash the PST, PDT, etc to timezone offsets) and it works now. Yay! Oh, but Boo hoo! I'm too new to vote your answer up.